# How to fetch all rows with group by value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

#### I have a table say table1 which has 3 columns like id, name and age.

Records available in table1,

```
id  name       age
-------------------
1   xxx        12
2   yyy        21
3   zzz        12
4   aaa        19
5   ccc        21
6   fff        12
```

I need result like this,

```
id  name       age   same_age_count
-----------------------------------
1   xxx        12    3
2   yyy        21    2
3   zzz        12    3
4   aaa        19    1
5   ccc        21    2
6   fff         12    3
This is what my expected result.
```

**Note:**
same_age_count is the count value of repeated age in the table.

I have tried this query,

```
select *, count(age) as same_age_count from table1 group by(age);

id  name       age   same_age_count
-----------------------------------
1   xxx        12    3
2   yyy        21    2
3   aaa        19    1
```

but it returns 3 records only, please give me a query for my expected result..

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.same_age_count
FROM TableName T1
JOIN
(SELECT age,Count(age) as same_age_count
 FROM TableName
 GROUP BY age) T2
ON T1.age=T2.age
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    AGE   SAME_AGE_COUNT
1   xxx     12    3
2   yyy     21    2
3   zzz     12    3
4   aaa     19    1
5   ccc     21    2
6   fff     12    3
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cf4a6/2).

Comment: @SurendarKannan: Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied so that it could help others in future. If you don't know how to accept one, please [**read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql 8 or above you can use window functions.

select t1.*, count(t1.age) over (partition by t1.age) as same_age_count from table1 t1;